# поиск по строкам с помощью ajax+php

Tags: php, jquery

Есть такой интересный вопрос, хочу сделать что бы инфа с базы(PostgreSQL) выгружалась на сайт и по данной информации я уже проводил поиск.

Вот что у меня уже есть (index.php)(добавил строки которые формируются с база, для примера пока что 2):

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="ru">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport"
          content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/js/main.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/style.css">
    <title>Test</title>
</head>
<body>
<table>
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <td><input id="search" type="text" placeholder="search" autofocus>
</td>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="task">
<tr class="info-clients" style="display: table-row;">
    <td class="id">1</td>
    <td class="company">Protect</td>
    <td class="country">Ukraine</td>
    <td class="good">Beer</td>
</tr>
<tr class="info-clients" style="display: table-row;">
    <td class="id">2</td>
    <td class="company">Protect</td>
    <td class="country">Chaina</td>
    <td class="good">Gear</td>
</tr>
    <script>
        clients();
    </script>
    </tbody>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Далее мой main.js:

```
function clients() {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: "../../clients.php",
        cache: false,
        success: function (clients) {
            $('#task').html(clients);
        }
    });
}

jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    jQuery('#search').on('change click keyup', function () {
        var value = jQuery(this).val();
        var comp = jQuery('.company').val();
        var count = jQuery('.country').val();
        var good = jQuery('.good').val();
        if ((comp || count || good) != value) {
            jQuery('.info-clients').css('display', 'none');
        } else {
            jQuery('.info-clients').css('display', 'table-row');
        }
    })
});
```

И вот тут у меня начинается косяк, логика тут такова что при добавлении любого текста в input он сразу должен проходить через логику и показывать только те строки которые имею данные значения, но у меня при пустой показываются все а только начинаю любое слово вводить сразу все пропадает как будто совпадений не найдено, помогите голову 3 сутки ломаю что не так((

Для того что бы понимать что находиться в clients.php:

```
<?php

$conn = mysqli_connect('127.0.0.1','mysql', 'mysql', 'tryself', '3306');

if (!$conn) {
    exit ('MySQL error');
}

$users = mysqli_query($conn, 'SELECT * FROM clients WHERE 1');
while ($row=mysqli_fetch_array($users))
{
    print "<tr class='info-clients'><td class='id-company'>".$row['id']."</td><td class='email-company'>".$row['email']."</td><td class='company-company'>".$row['company']."</td><td class='country-company'>".$row['country']."</td><td class='good-company'>".$row['good']."</td></tr>";
}

?>
```

Comment: А где логика PHP? Может быть проблема в clients.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Значение тега получаете не правильно. Можно так:

```
var count = jQuery('.country').html();
```

второе как я понл функция clients();  должен запускатся при вводе символов значит его надо перенести в

```
if ((comp || count || good) != value) {
jQuery('.info-clients').css('display', 'none');
} else {
jQuery('.info-clients').css('display', 'table-row');
}
clients();
```

и ещё функция должна передавть value файлу "clients.php"

я бы немного изменил её:

```
function clients( value ) {
    $.ajax({
        url: "clients.php",
        method: "POST",
        data: { val : value },
        success: function (clients) {
            $('#task').html(clients);
        }
    });
}
```

ну и соответственно передавал бы аргумент в clients( value );

Comment: Немного не понял несколько вещей, для чего менять метод c GET на POST, если мы просто делаем выборку (в принципе по логике что я  прочитал я так понял что это из за строки о которой буду спрашивать дальше). Зачем нужна данная строка data: { val : value } и где ее еще надо прописывать, поскольку  у меня сразу в логах вылетает ошибка `value is not defined`. **Обновил инфу для того что бы увидеть всю картину работы.**

Comment: Вариант с методом "POST" и передачей "value" был написан для передачи значения с поля "input" файлу "clients.php".
Вижу что вы передавать ничего не обирались. Поэтому функцию "clients()" не нужно изменять.

Comment: Да, смысл был в том что я уже хотел делать поиск по уже сформированным строкам дабы убрать возможность инъекции, знаю что не удобно поскольку если список будет over 100500+ позиций то будет ппц как лагать но задание пока что дали на небольшой список и простую форму.